# How to create a floating image with no window background

Tags: graphics, front-end, gui-construction

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the most effective way to setup a Notebook with transparent background but solid contents?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/252/what-is-the-most-effective-way-to-setup-a-notebook-with-transparent-background-b)

When MMA 8 starts, a floating image of spikey is shown. As you can see the image has no rectangular border and the contents of the screen outside the spikey body are visible. We could say that the spikey image has a transparent background.

How do we achieve this effect in MMA?

This is my attempt:

```
(* Display splash screen for t seconds*)

DisplaySplash[ t_] := (splashnb = CreateWindow[DocumentNotebook[{Graphics[Disk[]] }], 
ShowCellBracket -> False, Deployed -> True, 
ShowGroupOpener -> False, WindowSize -> All, 
WindowMovable -> False, WindowElements -> {}, 
WindowFrame -> "Frameless", 
WindowFrameElements -> None,
Background -> None, 
WindowTitle -> None];

Pause[t];

NotebookClose[splashnb];)

(* Display splash screen for t seconds*)

DisplaySplash[5];
```

As you see, even if the window has `Background-> None`, a white rectangular background surrounds the black disk and covers the underlying screen contents. Changing the window opacity, changes also the disk opacity, so it is not an option.

Can you suggest a solution?

Comment: WindowFrameElements->None is not fully docuemted, but is apparently the only way to have a really invisible window (except for the white background)

Comment: I can't find it at the moment, but there was a similar question on StackOverflow, and I think it turned out that the background on certain types of windows (depending on the window frame) can be set to transparent on OS X but not on Windows.  I might be remembering wrong though, don't take my word for it.

Comment: @Szabolcs thank you. I am using Windows

Comment: WindowOpacity affects all elements of a window, not just its content area.

Comment: I think [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/252/125) is the  SO question Szabolcs is referring to.

Comment: @kguler yes these two questions are very similar