# How can I set an image as the background of a panel?

Tags: graphics

Is it possible to set an `Image` as the `Background` of a `Panel`? I've studied all the options in the Documentation center, but didn't find anything about it.

```
  image=Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/U6Pby.jpg"]
```

[image: Background Image]

```
  Panel[Style["This is Infratab", 
                Bold, 
                20,
                Editable -> False
               ], 
      Background -> image, Alignment -> Center, ImageSize -> {400, 400}
  ](*panel is closed*)
```

Instead of a color, I want to set `image` as background of the `Panel`.

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6961/57

Answer (score 2):

You could try the`Overlay` command:

```
image = ImageResize[ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Tiffany"}], 300];
Overlay[
 {ImageAdjust[image, {0, 0.5}], 
  Panel[
   Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10},
    PlotStyle -> {Thick, Red}, 
    ImageSize -> ImageDimensions[image]],
   Alignment -> Center,
   ImageSize -> ImageDimensions[image]
   ]}
 ]
```

[image]

Comment: ,sorry your code is also not working.I evaluated your code in my system.

Comment: try restarting Mathematica?

Comment: Already I tried ,still not working.

Comment: works for me, MacOS X Mountain Lion, Mathematica 8.0.1. Sorry, can't help.

Comment: @subbu What is your mma version? Is it a previous one than 8? `Overlay` is introduced in version 8.

Comment: @Silvia good thought - I [checked](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/13186/how-to-rotate-graphics3d-into-cdf) and subbu seems to be on 8...

Comment: hmm.. good checking.. +1 :)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
image = ExampleData[{"TestImage", "Man"}];
Panel[ImageCompose[image,
  Rasterize[Style["This is Infratab", Bold, 20, Yellow], 
   Background -> None]],
 Alignment -> Center, ImageSize -> {400, 400}]
```

[image]

Comment: ,you are specifying `image` as data with in `panel`,but I want to set `image` as Background to the `Panel`.

Comment: @ subbu -  That isn't possible. `Background` is just for colours.

Comment: ,that was I Know,just I am trying is it possible or not?