# How can I add a background to a stylesheet?

Tags: front-end, notebooks, options, stylesheet

In version 9 we can set the background to an image, however I'd like to save this into a stylesheet that can be installed.

Comment: Related: [how-can-i-set-an-image-to-be-the-notebooks-background](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/6961/how-can-i-set-an-image-to-be-the-notebooks-background)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

sample image you want to use as background:

```
image = Import["ExampleData/lena.tif"];
```

Create cell that you need to put in style definition:

```
Cell[StyleData["Notebook"],
 System`BackgroundAppearance -> image] // CellPrint
```

[image]

Open stylesheet editor (Format -> Edit StyleSheet...)

Copy the cell you just created and install stylesheet.

[image]

Comment: does this work also in version 8.x? Why is System`BackgroundAppearance displayed in red?

Comment: It doesn't work in v8.  Color should be black.