# Image background for cell?

Tags: front-end, image, stylesheet, cells, style

I'd like to make code Cells have a specific background image. I know [you can do this for Notebooks](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6961/121), but what about Cells?

This simple test fails:

```
ConvertImageToFullyScaledNinePatch[img_] := 
  Module[{paddedImage = ImagePad[img, 1, Black]}, 
   ReplaceImageValue[paddedImage, 
    Flatten[Outer[List, {0, #1}, {0, #2}] & @@ 
       ImageDimensions[paddedImage], 1] -> White]];

img = ConvertImageToFullyScaledNinePatch[
   ExampleData[{"TestImage", "JellyBeans"}]];

CellPrint@Cell["test", "Code", BackgroundAppearance -> img]
```

Comment: Without a link to the earlier Q&A `ConvertImageToFullyScaledNinePatch` is without context so I added a link.  I hope you don't mind.

Comment: Ah, I meant to include that, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Probably not ideal, but using OverlayBox (undocumented) can get you something:

```
img = ConvertImageToFullyScaledNinePatch[
               Import["https://addons.cdn.mozilla.net/static/img/docs/themes/header.jpg"]
      ];


CellPrint[
 Cell[BoxData[
   OverlayBox[{ToBoxes[img], "test"}, Alignment -> Center]], "Code", 
  CellFrameMargins -> 0, CellMargins -> 0, PageWidth -> 1600]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Since it is not editable anyway you can use documented `Overlay`.

Comment: @Kuba You are right of course, no need to get all complicated.

Comment: in reflection this is kind of a bad solution, but maybe someone can use it find a better one.