# Full screen image in slideshow?

Tags: front-end

Is it possible to make an image fill up and entire slide in a slideshow notebook  so that there are no cell brackets or any white space around it at all (when viewed in presentation mode of course)?

Comment: Your old question is clearly similar, can you relate to it and its answers? [How can I set an image to be the Notebook's background?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/6961/5478)

Comment: This is similar but totally different, perhaps I should have titled it "How to make a slideshow cell's background be an image"

Comment: @M.R. Probably you should rename the question because as currently written, it is a duplicate of the Q linked by Kuba. Also, I assume that you wish to remove cell brackets and any space around the cell but the cell should be editable and can contain something apart of the background image, am I correct?

Comment: @Alexey Not a dup, this is a complete different question (Notebook != Cell)