# Take screenshot of the entire desktop using Mathematica

Tags: front-end, warning-messages

Is it possible to get a screenshot of the entire desktop directly in *Mathematica*?

I am on Ubuntu running *Mathematica* 8. For some reason `GUIScreenShot[]` fails. But something like `GUIScreenShot[{{0, 500}, {0, 500}}]` works

It is strange that in the reference

```
GUIScreenShot[]
```

is  given as an example (last one), with the caption **Capture the entire screen:**. But when I copy it and paste it in a notebook, it expects a parameter! (I have included the code `` Needs["GUIKit`"] ``)

I get the error as shown in this image

[image: Screenshot of the image]

Comment: I am trying to automate a simple game (!). So grabbing it using an external program, then saving it as a file and importing the file again from within Mathematica is a tedious job (if not realtime). Also I am not sure if I can pipe the output of a program as input to Mathematica (I could not find a way to get it done with Run[] command! - i.e. the piping large output from external program)

Comment: `GUIScreenShot[]` works here (Win XP)

Comment: `GUIScreenShot[]` doesn't work for me (Arch Linux), it spits [this error message](http://pastebin.com/TNfnaFDu) on the terminal. Looks like a Linux issue...

Comment: It works fine on my win7_x64 and mma8.0.4 (although a syntax indicator). Didn't know this function before. [Very helpful!](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/252) Thanks and +1!

Comment: `GUIScreenShot[]` works in version 7 under Windows 7.

Comment: Works also in version 8 under XP Pro SP3.

Answer (score 16):

`GUIScreenShot[]` (without arguments) works perfectly fine on my Mac, although the front end syntax highlighter indicates a missing argument. As a workaround, you can explicitly give it the dimensions of your screen so that all of it is captured. Here's how you can programmatically get your screen size and use it:

```
Needs["GUIKit`"]
GUIScreenShot["FullScreenArea" /. Flatten@SystemInformation["Devices", "ScreenInformation"]]
```

Comment: This does not seem to work on Ubuntu .. Can any1 confirm this ...

Comment: @myaccount_ram I'm having the same problem, but with Arch Linux.

Comment: @myaccount_ram It doesn't work on Fedora.

Comment: I got ** Raster data contains 0 values per pixel; 3 or 4 are required with ColorFunction->RGBColor** under Linux 64.

Comment: @everyone: The issue seems to be something related to linux and not Mathematica. I would've helped if I could, but I don't have a license to use on my Linux machine.

Comment: So many uses. Look: ``Needs["GUIKit`"] Dynamic[out] FixedPoint[(Pause[1]; out = GUIScreenShot[]) &, 0]``

Answer (score 8):

In v11.2 you can just use `CurrentScreenImage[]`.

Answer (score 7):

A method from [Kuba](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/users/5478/kuba)'s [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/77989/17), no `` GUIKit` `` is needed. Tested on Mathematica 10.1.

```
Module[{masknb, img},
       masknb = CreateWindow[{}, WindowSize -> Full, Visible -> False];
       img = MathLink`CallFrontEnd[FrontEnd`NotebookImage[masknb]];
       NotebookClose[masknb];
       img
      ]
```

We can even make a fairly fast screen recorder from it:

```
Clear[maskWindow]
maskWindow[width_, height_, leftMarg_, topMarg_] :=
    CreateWindow[{},
        WindowSize -> {width, height},
        WindowMargins -> {{leftMarg, Automatic}, {topMarg, 0}},
        Visible -> False]

Clear[screenSnapshot]
screenSnapshot[window_] := 
    MathLink`CallFrontEnd[FrontEnd`NotebookImage[window]]

screenRecord = {};
recordingFlag = True;
Column[{
        "Click to stop recording:",
        Toggler[Dynamic[recordingFlag],
            {True -> Framed["Recording"], False -> Framed["Stopped  "]}
            ]
        }]

Module[{masknb},
        masknb = maskWindow[500, 300, 300, 200];
        While[recordingFlag,
            screenRecord = Join[screenRecord, {screenSnapshot[masknb]}]
            ];
        NotebookClose[masknb];
        ];
screenRecord = Image /@ screenRecord;
ListAnimate[screenRecord]
```

[image: MMA screen recorder]

Comment: Extremely Fast!!!!! Very impressive answer~ xie xie la~ but still, are there faster methods?

Comment: @Wjx Thanks! For better performance, I'd go win API + NETLink.

Answer (score 5):

Confirming @R.M's answer (WinXP, Mac OSX 10.8)

[image]

Comment: why not a comment? Also, why are you hiding your porn tabs? ;)

Comment: @rm -rf The porn tabs are there ... look again

Comment: @rm -rf Re: Why not a comment. I like the conceptual [_Droste Effect_](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Droste_effect) produced by the image of a question asking for a screen cap on the answer's screen cap.

Comment: Doesn't work properly with more than one monitor. It only captures the primary monitor even if the MMA windows are on the other screen(s).

Comment: @belisarius `Nest[GUIScreenShot[], "", 10]`

Comment: @belisarius It's not a Droste effect until it is.

Comment: The Droste Effect: ``Dynamic[Export["C:\\droste.png", GUIScreenShot[]]; 
 Style[GUIScreenShot[], Magnification -> 1], UpdateInterval -> 3]``. When the `Dynamic` object is not visible, it is not updated (it is sufficient just to reduce the *Mathematica* window).

Answer (score 4):

Using `JLink`,you can do this

```
Needs["JLink`"];
InstallJava[];
robotclass = JavaNew["java.awt.Robot"];
LoadJavaClass["javax.imageio.ImageIO"];
LoadJavaClass["java.awt.Toolkit"];
screenSize = Toolkit`getDefaultToolkit[]@getScreenSize[];
image = robotclass@createScreenCapture[JavaNew["java.awt.Rectangle", 0, 0, screenSize@width, screenSize@height]];
ImageIO`write[image, "png",JavaNew["java.io.File", FileNameJoin[{Directory[], "test.png"}]]];
UninstallJava[]

Import["test.png"]
```

> [image]