# Capture screenshot of a certain window given its title

Tags: gui-construction, windows, external-calls

Is there a way to find the handle of a certain window and take a screenshot in Mathematica without having to call external programs? Something that connects with the API for the operating system.

Comment: does [CurrentNotebookImage](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CurrentNotebookImage.html)` give what you need?

Comment: ```CurrentScreenImage``` captures full screens or a rectangle from the screen.

Comment: Is this what you need: [56065](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/56065/5478)?

Answer (score 3):

**Update**

Another way! using

```
Notebooks[]
```

to list all the windows and then copy one of them to `Export`!

```
Export["newCapture.png", copySomethingAbove, ImageResolution -> 400]
```

See the picture as below!

[image]

**Original**

To control the  resolution of image, we can use `CreateDocument` to creat a new notebook, then write some code and run. `SetSelectedNotebook` can be used to chose the exact window and then capture it.

```
nb1 = CreateDocument[Plot[Sin[x], {x, -5, 5}, PlotStyle -> Red]];
nb2 = CreateDocument[Plot[Cos[x], {x, -5, 5}, PlotStyle -> Blue]];
SetSelectedNotebook[nb1];
Export["nb1-picture.png", %, ImageResolution -> 400]
SetSelectedNotebook[nb2]
Export["nb2-picture.png", %, ImageResolution -> 400]
```