# How can I make notebook cell's background become transparent?

Tags: output-formatting

How can I make notebook cell's background become transparent?
And can be saved as html with the translucent or transparent effect?

One of the use is in HTML files, the background of cell hides the background of the web page's background. I wish there would be some setting in Mathematica and could be changed to HTML with transparent background, if no such direct manipulation, then should post process the HTML source file.

Also, it it possible to make an Image as the background of the Notebook? something like the part effect of some slideshow stylesheet?

Comment: Related, possible duplicate: [(252)](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/252/121) -- please clarify how your question is different, if it is.

Comment: What good would this be? What in your notebook is behind the cell background that you want to make visible?

Comment: @m_goldberg Hi, The use is in HTML files, the background of cell hides the background of the web page's background.
I wish there would be some setting in Mathematica and could be changed to HTML with transparent background, if no such direct manipulation, then should post process the HTML source file.

Answer (score 2):

You may wish to link your own `.css` file with the background of cells set to be transparent.

Answer (score 1):

Possible solution:

```
SetOptions[Rasterize, Background -> None]
Export["123.html", EvaluationNotebook[], "MathOutput" -> "PNG"]
```

It produces html with transparent png files. Unfortunately `Background->None` doesn't work directly in html `Export`. Then you can easily change the background in your html:

[image]

Another possibility (without `Background -> None`) is

```
Export["123.html", EvaluationNotebook[], "MathOutput" -> "SVG"]
```