# Make Mathematica look like a terminal

Tags: front-end, linux

I know similar things have been asked before but the responses there do not seem to work for me so I wanna give this another try. I like editing code in vim in a terminal. I set the screen transparent black. I would love to have a similar set-up in Mathematica. I know how to make the screen black but I do not seem to achieve making it transparent. So, can I make a notebook look black and transparent?

Comment: Is this what you want? https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/252/what-is-the-most-effective-way-to-setup-a-notebook-with-transparent-background-b

Comment: Based on the use of the word "vim", I'm assuming that this is on Linux.  In which case, WindowOpacity will have no effect.

Comment: @Kuba I have tried this and my computer freezes

Comment: @ihojnicki it is indeed in Linux

Comment: I share frustration of yours... why is the culture so different among mathematica users?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure that you can do it natively, but you can try programs like this one: [windowtop](https://windowtop.info/).

In alternative you can use Mathematica in a terminal, for example, in cmd:

```
"C:\Program Files\Wolfram Research\Mathematica\12.0\math.exe"
```

In Powershell

```
& "C:\Program Files\Wolfram Research\Mathematica\12.0\math.exe"
```

You cannot see any graphics this way, though...